# How to set multiple field for HyperLinkColumn in a DataGrid using DataNavigateUrlField

Tags: .net, datagrid

I am trying to create a DataGrid with a HyperLinkColumn that uses two fields for the url.
I am using Vb, VS 2005, .net 2

I am getting this exception:
"A field or property with the name 'PrimKey,IsCommercial' was not found on the selected data source."

I am not sure why, I have check the following.

- The fields are all spelt correctly.
- The fields are in the datasource.
- The fields all work as simple Bound Columns.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn SortExpression="LogNo" DataNavigateUrlField="PrimKey, IsCommercial" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Clarifications.aspx?PrimKey={0}&IsCommercial={1}" DataTextField="LogNo" HeaderText="LogNo" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this with a TemplateColumn.
Example:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="LogNo" SortExpression="LogNo">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="../Clarifications.aspx?PrimKey=<%# Container.DataItem("PrimKey").ToString() & "&IsCommercial=" & Container.DataItem("IsCommercial") %>"><%#Eval("LogNo")%></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the [DataNavigateUrlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datanavigateurlfield.aspx) supports multiple fields but you could easily convert your DataGrid into GridView whose HyperLinkField supports [DataNavigateUrlFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlfields.aspx)

Alternatively, if you still want to use DataGrid you would need to manually build the NavigateUrl like so:

**UPDATE:**

I should have tested the previous suggestion more thoroughly before posting.. Yes, it was intended to be inside a TemplateColumn:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="LogNo" HeaderText="LogNo">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "../Clarifications.aspx?PrimKey=" & Container.DataItem("PrimKey") & "&IsCommercial=" & Container.DataItem("IsCommercial") %>'><%# Container.DataItem("LogNo")%></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I am supporting a legacy app where changing to a GridView is not an option in this case.

Comment: I tried your alternative but it generates this exception. Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkColumn does not have a DataBinding event.